# Nodemailer in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

Recently, i need send email from angular7. I get install `nodemailer`
but. How i can start and get implements it?
any reference doc or guide ?

i tried a `contact.js` initialized in `angular.json`:

```
"...":[...],
 "scripts": ["./contact.js"]
```

#### contact.js

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');


var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'ejre2331@gmail.com',
    pass: 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'ejre2331@gmail.com',
  to: 'tomyfriendd@yahoo.com',
  subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
  text: 'That was easy!'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
```

kind regards

Comment: You simply won't be able to send an email using Nodemailer from the client-side, in this case Angular. Nodemailer needs to be executed from a Node server/API solution such as Express. Create a Node based server/API, expose an endpoint on that server/API, using HttpClient from Angular to send data to that endpoint, send the email using Nodemailer on the server/API using that data. Another alternative could be using serverless solutions like cloud functions/lambdas instead of creating your own server.

Comment: That's an option, but it doesn't need to be a specific stack or framework. It really even just be a simple Express application with a single endpoint that takes in a simple application/json payload then sends the email using Nodemailer. The point is that you will not able to execute Nodemailer from the browser directly.

Comment: Thanks, it has helped me!